# Replacing fuel pump strainer

Tags: honda, fuel-system, fuel-filter

I have a 2004 Honda CR-V. It does not have a fuel filter but rather a strainer in the fuel pump assembly. I'm used to having cars with separate fuel filters in line with a fuel rail that you replace every few years, but replacing this strainer seems like a lot more work (and obscure O-rings and gaskets to replace, according to the factory service manual).

Can I expect any noticeable benefit by replacing the fuel pump strainer?

Answer (score 1):

If you live in an area with dirty fuel, then yes probably. If the fuel you purchase is normal then replace at the manufacturer's recommended interval.

The other option is to fit an in-line filter, BUT you have to make sure that the filter and fittings are rated for the pressure and be aware of the safety issues when changing it ie making sure the pressure is released safely before disconnecting it...